# Do the screw holes in bones get fill in after get removed?

Tags: bone-fractures

Due to a car accident I have two holes from external fixation in my tibia. I'm 22 years old,. So I was wondering if these holes get fill in with new bone as any fracture or just stay with soft tissue forever.

Comment: What did your doctor say when you asked him?

Comment: I haven't asked him yet. My next control is on May